# Get places around location given a distance

Tags: android, google-places-api

Since Google has changed their places API then I think this question is no longer a duplicated of previous questions

On Android, I am interested in retrieving hospitals places that are within 20 km if person location.

When I check the Android Places SDK (https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/current-place)
Then I see that they have "getCurrentPlace" but this does not let me specify distance and also it seems it is return the current place only!

However, the webAPI seems to give more control but I am not sure if the norm is to use web api in Android app.

Many websites talk about using the GeoCoding api to get places which does not make sense because that api to do conversion but somehow it is getting places.

So I am confused, what do I need to do/use to meet the requirement I have?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote an app once couldn't find this so used this way:

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
builder.append("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=")
        .append(mLocation.getLatitude())
        .append(",")
        .append(mLocation.getLongitude())
        .append("&radius=")
        .append(radius)
        .append("&types=restaurant&sensor=true&key=AIzaSyC4BuDhg8b384A5VXCVooPLwiOeKWEC31M");
```

Just use toString() on it and then request a GET You'll get an array in json and do what you need with it.